# JQuery remove and add span-class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have two spans with links that a user can click, and when a span is clicked it remove a class and adds another class on the click one:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<span class="resCheck label label-success">
  <a data-method="get" class="resCheckLink" href="trafikskola?utf8=%E2%9C%93&amp;query=lund&     
   amp;sort=asc">Cheap prices</a>
</span>
<span class="resCheck label">
  <a class="resCheckLink" data-method="get" href="trafikskola?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=lund&  
  sort=desc">Expensive prices</a>
</span>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function(){
    $('.resCheckLink').click(function(e){
        $('.resCheck.label').removeClass('label-success');
        $(this).parent().addClass('label-success')
    });
});
```

But it dosent work, it dosent add and remove the classes, how can I fix this?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, but I don't think parent() is the right solution.

Comment: it would be easier if you used toggleClass() instead of manually adding and removing the class.

Comment: I consistently have problems with the .parent() selector not doing what you'd expect it to do. Try swapping out .parent() with .closest('.resCheck') - I find that the closest selector generally does the same thing, with the added bonus that if you tweak the hierarchy (what if that <a> needs to be inside another <span> down the road?), it usually still finds the right elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$(function(){
    $('.resCheckLink').click(function(e){
        $('.resCheck').removeClass('label-success');
       $(this).parent().addClass('label-success');
    });
});
```

Comment: it first set the class on the clicked on and then it changes back on the first one. same thing.

Comment: @@SHUMAcupcake  now check it

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$(function(){
    $('.resCheckLink').click(function(e){
        $('.resCheck').removeClass('label-success');
        $(this).parent().addClass('label-success');
    });
});
```

**[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KXDJE/13/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$(function(){
    $('.resCheckLink').click(function(e){
        $('span.resCheck').removeClass('label-success');
        $(this).parent().addClass('label-success')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work actually, I imagine you're styling the element incorrectly or something? I added `return false` to prevent the link functioning.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78Uk8/)

```
$(function(){
    $('.resCheckLink').click(function(e){
        $('.resCheck.label').removeClass('label-success');
        $(this).parent().addClass('label-success');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: The change I made to the code was to `return false` so I could test it. Removing that and it's the exact piece of code in your question. It looks correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(function(){
   $('.resCheckLink').click(function(e){
         $('.resCheck').removeClass('label-success');
         $(this).parent().addClass('label-success')
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are removing and adding same class, so you will not be able to monitor actually,

```
$('.resCheck.label').removeClass('label-success');
    $(this).parent().addClass('label-success');
```

so Please create another class with different style and then try, with answer given by PSR above.

that will do :)